# Kubernetes Pods - Inject environment variable from host node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I have a container with the following spec:

```
containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: REDACTED
        env:
        - name: DISPLAY
          value: ":10.0"   <---------------------
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: "production"
        - name: ENDPOINT
          value: REDACTED
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: x11
          mountPath: /tmp/.X11-unix
      volumes:
      - name: x11
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/.X11-unix
```

sidenote: What this is doing is it's allowing me to render components on the host node, but perform the computation inside my container.

Right now I have DISPLAY hardcoded to ":10.0", but I want to do something like:

```
env:
        - name: DISPLAY
          value: ":$HOST_DISPLAY"
```

Which will mount the host node's DISPLAY variable (rather than hardcoding and guessing what it will be), so that if a node has ":0" or any other variable set it will forward/inject it into the container dynamically.

Any way to accomplish this? If it helps I can use an ansible operator

Edit to further explain:

Imagine a pod that was a simple http server that when you hit it with a browser, showed you the operating system of the node it is being run on. Lets say the node had an environment variable called OPERATING_SYSTEM. Node A has OPERATING_SYSTEM=Windows  Node B has OPERATING_SYSTEM=Linux. How could I configure this pod to display the node's operating system. *NOT THE CONTAINER OPERATING SYSTEM*

Another example:

Imagine a pod that was a simple http server that when you hit it with a browser, it gave you back the ID of the node that it is running on. Lets say Node 1 has an environment variable called NODE_ID=123 and Node 2 has an environment variable called NODE_ID=456. When any pod gets scheduled on one of these two arbitrary nodes, it can access these NODE environment variables to correctly display which node it's running on

I almost want to do this, except with node.fields: https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to achieve. You can consider using `ConfigMap`, `Kustomize` or `initContainer`, however you need to describe this scenario bit differently.

Comment: I'm trying to pull a environment variable from the node that is running the pod, and being able to access that env variable from within the pod/container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to pass environment variables.

1. Define env variables in container, for example like in [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container).
2. Define in Pod/Deployment config like [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config).
3. From Secrets from [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables).

To pass new environment variables to container you need to use `ConfigMap` or `Secret`.

Unfortunately, that what you want to achieve is impossible to obtain in pure Kubernetes due to `Kubernetes concepts`. As per [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/):

> A Pod encapsulates an application’s container (or, in some cases,
>   multiple containers), storage resources, a unique network IP, and
>   options that govern how the container(s) should run. A Pod represents
>   a unit of deployment: a single instance of an application in
>   Kubernetes, which might consist of either a single container or a
>   small number of containers that are tightly coupled and that share
>   resources.

If you will `kubectl describe <pod-name>` you will have only name of host, because that's all what Kubernetes needs. Kubernetes make sure to run whole deployment application, no mather on what node (unitl you specify `nodeSelector`). It's how Kubernetes was designed. For detailed information you should reat [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/).

You can add some `tags` with `ansible`, `python`, etc to question. Maybe if you would use some scripts/libraries it could be done, but you will not achieve this using `pure Kubernetes`.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. It makes sense why you wouldn't want that, and I assume my usecase is pretty niche. Maybe I can have a map of hostname->DISPLAY variable and just register all my nodes in there, and somehow pull that hostname at a script level and assign it there. Thanks for the response, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigMap. create a key=value in configure map and reference in your env

https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b

Comment: While this is definitely useful, and a very good source article,I dont think it solves the problem. Creating a config map would set all of my containers to use the same config value. At the time of Pod creation I do not know what node I'll be on, and each node can have a different DISPLAY variable on the node itself. So I need to be sourcing the variable from the node itself and unfortunately a config wont work

Comment: Imagine a pod that was a simple http server that when you hit it with a browser, showed you the operating system of the node it is being run on. Lets say the node had an environment vriable called OPERATING_SYSTEM. Node A has OPERATING_SYSTEM=Windows  Node B has OPERATING_SYSTEM=Linux. How could I configure this pod to display the node's operating system. *NOT THE CONTAINER OPERATING SYSTEM*